# Printing fields using awk

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

```
< pool.sam awk '
  /./ {printf $1}
  {printf $7+1,"\t"}
  {printf $3,"\t"}
  {
    if($2 !=16) {print "\t", "+";} else {print "\t","-";}
    {printf $4,"\t" ,length($10)+$4, "\t", "1"}
  }'
```

I am getting all the values, but in a weird manner. 
I am printing 7 values,

value1 value2 value3     value7

I want all these 7 values, separated by a TAB, in each Line.

Comment: It would help if you included sample text from `pool.sam` and an example of the output you are after...

Comment: `value1 value2 value3 value7` are only four (4) values. your script references up to ten values (`$10`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `printf` is a *print formatted* function, `print` concatenates parameters.

Looks like you need to check out the `printf` function (or both).

In short it is:

```
printf <format, <parameter1>[, <parameter2>, ...] | text>
```

The letter `%` in a format denotes *here comes a parameter that should be formatted as ...*. Format can hold special sequences like `\t`, `\n`. Printf does *not* terminate output by newline. If only one argument is given it is normally printed as is.

---

If it is a number the default formatting is "`%.6g`":

```
CODE  : printf 1.123456789
RESULT: 1.12346
```

If e.g. `$1` is `1.123456789` it is normally treated as text, as in:

```
CODE  : printf $1
RESULT: 1.123456789
CODE  : printf $1+0 # Force conversion to number
RESULT: 1.12346
```

---

When you give more then one argument the first one is used as format and the rest as parameters. If to few parameters are given to fulfill the pattern the behavior is ***undefined***.

```
printf "%d %s\n", 123, "hello"
         || | |    |      |
         || | |    |      +----- Parameter 2
         || | |    +------------ Parameter 1
         || | +----------------- Print new-line
         || +------------------- Print parameter 2 as string
         |+--------------------- Print literal space
         +---------------------- Print parameter 1 as digit

printf "%d %s\n", 123, "hello"
# Gives: 123 hello
printf "%d %s\n", "hello", 123
# Gives: 0 123
printf "%d %s\n", 123
# Gives undefined result (according to format one parameter is missing)
```

And if arguments are given without any placeholder the are discarded:

```
printf "%d", 123
# Gives: 123
printf "%d", 123, 22
# Gives: 123
printf "%d", 123, 22, "\t", "foo", 5566, 12.55, "\n", "blah"
# Gives: 123
```

The `%` character denotes *"here is a conversion specification"*. If a non valid specification is given, as in one that is not defined by `awk`, the behavior is ***unspecified***. Other text is treated as normal text.

```
printf "Hello %w", "what"
# Usually: Hello %w
# But no guarantee

printf "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"
# Result: ABC
```

In your code you frequently use input from file as format for printf. If those fields are not `printf` formats they are printed as normal text. Parameters are discarded.

```
# Example, say:
#     $4 = "%d %s\n"
#     $8 = "33.2"
#     $9 = "good"
printf $4, $8, $9
#
# Result: 33 good

# Say:
#     $4 = "14"
#     $8 = "33.2"
#     $9 = "good"
printf $4, $8, $9
#
# Result: 14
printf $4, "\t", $8, "\t", $9
#
# Result: 14
```

---

***Your script formatted:***

```
< pool.sam awk '
# 1.
/./ {                   # IF line not empty THEN
    printf $1           #   print field 1
}                       # ENDIF
# 2.
{
    printf $7 + 1, "\t" # printf with format = $7 + 1 and parameter <tab>
}
# 3.
{
    printf $3, "\t"     # printf with format = $3 and parameter <tab>
}
# 4.
{
    # 4.1
    if ($2 != 16) {       # IF field 2 is not 16 THEN
        print "\t", "+";  #    print <tab> + "+" (Terminate with newline)
    } else {              # ELSE
        print "\t", "-";  #    print <tab> + "-" (Terminate with newline)
    }                     # ENDIF

    # 4.2
    {
        printf $4, "\t", length($10) + $4, "\t", "1"
        # printf: pattern="field 4"
        #         parameters=<tab>, length of field 10 + field 4
    }
}
'
```

---

***Say you have:***

```
$ cat pool.sam
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

That would give you (using numbering in code above):

```
1.   printf "1"`                    => `1`
2.   printf 8, "\t"`                => `8`
3.   printf "3", "\t"               => `3`
4.1  print  "\t", "+"               => `<tab>+<new-line>`
4.2  printf "4", "\t", 6, "\t", "1" => `4`
```

Final result:

```
183    +
4
```

---

A rewrite that might get you somewhat on the way:

```
awk '
/./ {
    printf "%s%d\t%d\t", $1, $7 + 1, $3

    if ($2 != 16) {
        printf "+"
    } else {
        printf "-"
    }

    printf "%d\t%d\t1\n", $4, length($10) + $4
}
' pool.sam
```

The if statement, (in danger of confusing you), can also be written in one go as:

```
printf "%s", $2 != 16 ? "+" : "-"
```

---

Read up on format strings and `printf`. The align format is often very useful, as is formatting of floats etc.

```
right_pad=-10
printf "%*s: %5d\n", right_pad, "vix", 23
printf "%*s: %5d\n", right_pad, "popul", 336
printf "%*s: %5.2f\n", right_pad, "vidi", 42.129542488
printf "%5s %-10d +%d\n", "OK", 33, 44
```

Output:

```
vix       :    23
popul     :   336
vidi      : 42.13
   OK 33         +44
```

Easiest, at least I find it, is to use a script instead of command-line when playing around.

Comment: 'code'
      cat $lastPartGenome.sam | awk '
       function tag(){
   return $7+1;
   }
   function strand(){
            if($2==16)
    return "-";
   
      else
    return "+";
     }
     function printFields(){
    if(($3 !~ /\*/) && ($1 ~ /^[A-Z]/) )
    {
     print $1"\t"tag()"\t"$3"\t"strand()"\t"$4"\t"length($10)+$4"\t""1"
 
    }
    }
  printFields()
   '   >   $lastPartGenome.bed

This is what I finally did. This helped me keep my code organized and arrange it. 
I was unable to understand the If syntax given above.

Comment: @DeathMetal: Expanded on the answer, but had a browser-crash, so I gave up ... Anyhow to recap in short. Yes. Splitting up code can be helpful in both maintaining and understanding the code. (Though if it is performance critic – one should also benchmark.) I usually split out things that I do more then once (or if it is code I can have use for elsewhere as a function). For the *if* statement check out [ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:‎) – They can be quite helpful, especailly when it comes to printing text.

Answer (score 3):

you are running a lot of `printf`s for that job.
why not simply do something like

```
cat pool.sam |\
 awk '/./ {printf $1,$7+1,"\t"$3,"\t",($2!=16)?"+","-",$4,"\t",length($10)+$4,"\t1"}}'
```

Comment: > 'cat file.sam | awk ' function tag(){ return $7+1; >}    function strand(){ if($2==16) return "-"; >else      return "+"; } function printFields(){ if(($3 >!~ /*/) && ($1 ~ /^[A-Z]/) ) { print $1"\t"tag()"\t"$3"\t"strand()"\t"$4"\t"length($10)+$4"\t""1" } } printFields() ' > file2.bed '

Sorry, I don't know how post code in comments.  <br/>
@umlaute - now it is only one. I was unable to understand if ()?: so had switched to normal/unsophisticated if. :)

Comment: @DeathMetal for posting code in comments, use backquotes. as for the `()?:`, this is an [ordinary ternary conditional expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)